# Sails JS mongo connection issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have written web services in Sails JS. The sails js app was running correctly, but suddenly it stoped working. I am not getting what is the issue. When I am trying to restart the server using `node app.js` command.
It's giving me following error:

> Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]   at [object
>   Object].
>   (/root/tresscove-server/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:549:74)
>   at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)   at [object
>   Object].
>   (/root/tresscove-server/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
>   at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)   at Socket.
>   (/root/tresscove-server/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
>   at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)   at net.js:440:14   at
>   process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)

It is giving me the connection issue. But my database is on the different server and my `config/connections.js` contains following code:

```
mongoDbServer: {
      adapter: 'sails-mongo',
      host: process.env.MONGO_HOST,
      //host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      // user: 'username',
      // password: 'password',
      database: 'tresscove'
  }
```

The developer before me have set the environment variable `MONGO_HOST`. I don't know what was the value of that variable. How to set its value? How to solve this issue? The whole app has stoped working. Please help.

Comment: could u share your mongod log too? and also `process.env.MONGO_HOST` is an environment variable! find the cammands according to your os!

Answer (score 0):

Give the IP address of the remote database

Eg: host:"192.168.2.5"

Tnx

Comment: I have tried this. But still it is giving me same error.

Comment: Check config/model.js

Comment: connection:"mongoDbServer"

Comment: 1. For the first time only set config/model.js  ** migrate: "alter"**
2. Stop the server and set config/model.js **migrate:"safe"** and then start it

Comment: Sorry...i have no idea and tnx